# Access JSON data field from npm results

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, npm

How would I access `DepDateTime` from the first object properly?

My current attempt:

```
var nodeSkanetrafiken = require('node-skanetrafiken');

var from = { name: 'Bjärred centrum', id: 62025, type: 0 };
var to = { name: 'Lund C', id: 81216, type: 0 };
nodeSkanetrafiken.getJourneys({ from: from, to: to, action: 'next' }, function(results, err) {
    console.log(results);
    console.log(results.SequenceNo[0].DepDateTime);

});
```

The JSON result:

```
[ { SequenceNo: [ '0' ],
    DepDateTime: [ '2017-11-12T
    ArrDateTime: [ '2017-11-12T
    DepWalkDist: [ '0' ],
    ArrWalkDist: [ '0' ],
    NoOfChanges: [ '0' ],
    Guaranteed: [ 'false' ],
    CO2factor: [ '30' ],
    NoOfZones: [ '3' ],
    PriceZoneList: [ '12000234,
    FareType: [ 'Normaltaxa' ],
    Prices: [ [Object] ],
    JourneyKey: [ '181871536220
    RouteLinks: [ [Object] ],
    Distance: [ '12128' ],
    CO2value: [ '0.072' ] },
  { SequenceNo: [ '1' ],
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(results[0].DepDateTime[0]);`

It will give you the value of `DepDateTime`.

Comment: Your welcome. :) Do accept the answer if it helped you.